# Using if statement

Tags: qt, signals, signals-slots

I want to display an image called image1 when a button1 is pressed and image2 when button2 is pressed. In order to do this I want to use 'if' statement. I wrote the following code:

```
if(ui->button1->clicked())
image.load(":/CondScrnIns.png");
else if(ui->button2->clicked())
image.load(":/CondScrnInsCentric.png");
```

but while executing these statements I'm getting the following error:

```
void QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) is protected
```

what function should I use insted of clicked()??

Comment: You have to use Signals and Slots, take a look to this document: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create slots for each buttons's clicked signal and the do image.load in there.

```
connect(button1, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT(button1Clicked()));
connect(button2, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT(button2Clicked()));
```

Then in button1Clicked() and button2Clicked() slots you can put in the code to load the image or resize the dialog box whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `image.load()` statements in the respective event handlers. You cannot check for `button->clicked()` in an if statement like that.

Look at this page: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2758

Comment: Ok, but if I want to use the button->clicked() in a different way in if statement, like shape changing dialog box i.e., if I click on a button the shape of the dialog box should change and if i click other one it should come to its original size, then how should I use it??

Comment: If you want anything to happen when a button is clicked, all the associated code must go into the event handler function. 
The clicked() function doesn't return any value - there's no point using it in an if statement.